# How do i connect the php file to connect database using IBM Bluemix?

Tags: php, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-plugin

**I have some problem**

**code line**

```
$servername="us--------03.cleardb.net";

$user="be9-------0";

$pass="f9-------";

$db="ad_50f-------fa6a";    

$con = mysql_connect($servername, $user, $pass, $db);
mysql_select_db($db);
```

**My Requirement**

I implement this line code could not be working than how should be connect database in ibm bluemix!!

plz given me solution..

Comment: Could you please improve your question? What is not working? Include any logs so someone can help you.

Answer (score 1):

mysql_connect is deprecated.
Use this code as an example:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($mysql_server_name, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    die();
}
```

Your composer.json needs to have:

```
{
  "require": {
    "ext-mysqli": "*"
  }
}
```

https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/php-mysql   See: db.php and composer.json

To view the logs, use this command:

```
cf logs <yourappname> --recent
```